# Ubuntu 20.04 loses WiFi adaptor (Atheros AR9485 / Belkin)

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on an old computer and every time I wake up the computer from sleep the WiFi drops and there is no way to connect it back (also rarely happens randomly when device is not put to sleep).

The wifi card is an Atheros AR9485 (internal) and is running using `ath9k` & everything is up-to-date

I tried plugging in a Belkin USB WiFi dongle and it disables itself with the PCI card every time.

#### Detailed information:

When it does not work `rfkill list` shows `phy0` (the PCI card) as Hard blocked and there is no way I found that would enable it again besides restarting the computer. (The dongle is not shown as blocked but is still disabled)

If I soft block `phy0` with `rfkill` its shutdowns the dongle too.

I also tried removing the Atheros card from `network-management` and it didn't change anything.

**Debug info when everything is running smooth (no dongle) :**

`ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 18:67:b0:40:f4:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 870  bytes 90566 (90.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 870  bytes 90566 (90.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a01:cb11:403:2100:d0d8:a6ca:c7b:9b10  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a01:cb11:403:2100:8edf:fd97:4e60:42a4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::6091:8aac:3e3:b613  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 24:fd:52:99:40:2d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 37519  bytes 46147156 (46.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 89  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16308  bytes 2312226 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricant: Qualcomm Atheros
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       numéro de série: 24:fd:52:99:40:2d
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-40-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources : irq:16 mémoire:f7900000-f797ffff mémoire:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: enp3s0
       version: 06
       numéro de série: 18:67:b0:40:f4:f2
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       ressources : irq:19 portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:f7800000-f7800fff mémoire:f2100000-f2103fff
```

`lspci | grep -i wireless`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

**Debug info when nothing works (no dongle) :**

`ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 18:67:b0:40:f4:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 10373  bytes 880405 (880.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10373  bytes 880405 (880.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ       
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricant: Qualcomm Atheros
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       numéro de série: 24:fd:52:99:40:2d
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-40-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources : irq:16 mémoire:f7900000-f797ffff mémoire:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: enp3s0
       version: 06
       numéro de série: 18:67:b0:40:f4:f2
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       ressources : irq:19 portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:f7800000-f7800fff mémoire:f2100000-f2103fff
```

`lspci | grep -i wireless`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

`cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`:

```
[Connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Comment: What does `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` show?

Comment: It sais : `[Connection] wifi.powersave = 3`

Comment: Change it to 2; that will disable power-saving. You'll need to reboot after making this change.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ! Just tried, set to 2, save, check file with cat, reboot, sleep, wake up and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: This works on my Mint 19.3 system (based on Ubuntu 18.04); tried it with 2 different WiFi dongles. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: As I said in the question I already tried removing the card from `network-management` to rely only on the dongle and it doesn't work, I don't think is has something to do with `network-management`.